# Select from same table, different rows, different columns

Tags: mysql

My MySQL skills are very basic, so What I need (if possible) is a single `SELECT` statement that selects *different* columns from *different* rows in *the same* table. Most Google comes up with has to do with combining different tables or selecting same columns from different rows.

**Table**

```
id  |  c1  |  c2  |  c3  |  c4  |  c5  |  c6  |  c7  
-----------------------------------------------------   
1   | THIS | THIS | THIS |   a  |   a  |   a  |   a  
2   |   a  |   a  |   a  |   a  | THIS | THIS |   a
```

I'd like to select columns **c1, c2, c3** from row 1 and **c5, c6** from row 2. Column names and id numbers are known.

I could fire two queries and combine the data:

```
   SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM table WHERE id=1
   SELECT c5,c6 FROM table WHERE id=2
```

or I can fetch all the columns from the two rows simultaniously and filter out the data I need afterwards

```
   SELECT c1,c2,c3,c5,c6 FROM table WHERE id=1 OR id=2
```

My question: is there a `SELECT` statement that combines the two so I get the combined results in one query?

I found out `UNION` could work, but that only works if the number of columns selected is the same in both select-statements. And in this case, the aren't.

Any help would be appreciated.

**[edit]** See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers above still didn't do exactly what I wanted, because those queries returned two rows and/or messed with the column names.

In the end it turned out to be pretty simple:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM table WHERE id=1) AS t1,
FROM (SELECT c5,c6 FROM table WHERE id=2) AS t2
```

it returns one row, containing the values for c1, c2, c3, c5 and c6 with their corresponding column names

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` if you select a constant value for the missing fields:

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM table WHERE id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT c5, c6, NULL c3 FROM table WHERE id=2
```

With your sample data this will give you:

```
c1   c2   c3
THIS THIS THIS
THIS THIS NULL
```

Comment: I'm going to try that. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

you can just do a conditional column select instead of messing with union if you want :)

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN c1 ELSE c5 END
    CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN c2 ELSE c6 END
    CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN c3 ELSE NULL END
FROM table
```